# is it possible to access one class file to access its methods or variable by a service and another by an activity AT THE SAME TIME?

Tags: android, service

I have a class named PatientDetails in which i am storing the values from the xml and then need to access its variables and method from the service as well from the activity at the same point of time ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical multi thread scenario. You can do it without any troubles as long as you are just reading the data.

If you are reading the data from patient details class through your activity and writing data to it through your service you will get into run time exceptions. You have carefully synchronize the variables or methods in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

One way to share a 'helper' class is to hold a 'static' reference to a single instance of it in the `Application` component of your app. Example...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static detailsHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        detailsHelper = new PatientDetails();
    }
}
```

When you need to use the 'helper' in any other component such as an `Activity` or `Service` you simply reference it by the `Application` name as follows...

```
MyApp.detailsHelper.doSomething();
```

Technically speaking, under default conditions there is no such occurrence of two components accessing something *at the same time* because an Android `Application` and all of its components exist within a single `process` with a single `thread` of execution.

You should be very careful, however, if any of the components execute code which uses threads. For example, an `Activity` using an `AsyncTask` or perhaps using an `IntentService` which creates its own worker thread to do work. In this case, make sure any methods in the 'helper' class which write data, do so in a thread-safe manner.